# How can I manually add a resource to a Win32 resource file

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2008, win32gui

Visual Studio Win32 projects have a resource file. One can add and configure controls using a GUI interface. However I have a need to enter about 80 check boxes which is very tedious using the GUI. I can open the resource file in a text editor, but if I try and add a new control, Visual Studio cannot understand it. I used to be able to do that in the old WATCOM C++ IDE/compiler.

Clearly VS is doing something else that just making the resource file.

Is there any way to create and add resources (lie controls) by manually editing the rc file?

Comment: 80 checkboxes sounds like something you'd probably want to create dynamically, at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write the .rc file.
2. Use the resource compiler, `rc.exe` to compile the `.rc` file to a compiled resource, `.res`.
3. Pass the compiled resource to the linker.

Comment: To avoid using the command line would it be sufficient to delete the compiled rc files? Then on a rebuild VS would invoke the resource compiler? I have not tried but I think so. When I delete all the compiled output, I see the build invoke the resource compiler. But I have not tried it after manually editing the rc file.

Comment: I guess I asked the wrong question. I am sure the above will work but I wanted to avoid going through the command line and I wanted to go through VS. I am guessing that deleting all the output resource files in the project's /debug or /release directories will force VS to do a recompile of an edited rc file. All I know is if I manually edited the rc file in VS it would no longer work; I would get errors.

Comment: In other words while in VS I could only update the rc file using the graphics  tool.

Comment: I guess you did though I have not verified it. My bad.